# Can this be added to Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, code

First off, I would like to apologize if I am posting this in the incorrect location, as I am not sure where else to put this.

I use Stack Overflow all the time, and I have always wondered if a "select all" option could be added to large amounts of code.

Comment: Select all for what? For a code block?

Comment: @rene Yes, that is what I meant. Apologies if anything is not clear, English is not my main language

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It seems as if Stack Exchange is getting somewhat lazy at some of the things that need changing.

Comment: Yes, is that a problem?

Comment: Indeed it is...

Comment: They make different choices. Which is understandable as they run a business.

Comment: ...poorly run a business...   But that's just my opinion ^-^

Comment: Sure, a bit shortsighted though as a copy code button is not going to bring in half a million dollar per month. Having employers pay for jobs ads might...

Comment: True, but it will make users of Stack Exchange enjoy their websites more. (if you couldn't tell already, i don't particularly like this place)

Comment: No, I couldn't tell. I honestly thought you were trying to improve the site.

Comment: Well, yes, I am trying to improve the site, don't get me wrong. I'm just saying that the atmosphere here is not so great, and that it needs improvement.

Comment: I haven't noticed a stale atmosphere. Works for me.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand, but is manually selecting all the code text so difficult?  Is copying out the code done so often that dragging the mouse cursor from the top of the text to the bottom is so onerous a task as to need a special feature?

Comment: For me, at least, it is. I am an indie programmer with a small budget, and the laptop I have has a small screen resolution, which often isn't large enough for me to see an entire code block, let alone try to select it and copy it.

Comment: From yesterday, on SO Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344880/3001761